# Creating Bundling and Minification base on logged in user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am configuring bundles like below....

```
 private static void ConfigureBundles()
                {
                    BundleTable.Bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/App/JsPages")
                        .Include("~/Js/Pages/Page1.js")
                        .Include("~/Js/Pages/Page2.js")
                        .Include("~/Js/Pages/Page3.js")
                        );
                }
```

How can I modify bundles base on user authorization like let say current user has only access to `Page1.js` so I want modify

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var allowedPagesList = GetAllowedPagesList();

        //How can I modify bundle here so in return view. it only contains allowed pages js
        //like this user might not include page2.js
        return View();
    }        
}
```

I might be going in wrong direction to solve this problem so can any one help to solve this issue?

Comment: do you want it to be dynamic? otherwise you can create as many bundle as you want and include on that page. load your common bundles in _layout.cshtml and all specific bundles on related view.

Comment: yes it will be dynamic not hardcoded because users permission can be set via UI

Comment: well, I have done similar thing but in my case I write to a specific .js file after minification and that file is included on _layout.cshtml which every time contains different contents (javascript code) as per page requirenments

Comment: if this is what you need, then I can post code

Comment: This is an unnecessary use of bundles.  Bundles are meant to generate a single script file that gets cached by the server and by browsers.  If you are modifying it each load, then you don't need a bundle in the first place.  Just use a `section` or a partial view.